Power BI Report Builder: propagate value of parent column group
I have a problem in Power BI Report Builder.
As dataset I have a table similar to this:



ID
Parent Group
Child Group
Count




1
A
A1
1


2
A

1


3
A
A2
1



And i have to generate a Report Builder tablix like this:



ID
A






A1
A2


--
--
--


1
X



2
X
X


3

X



So I have to populate rows with the rules:

if the orginal row is related to a valued Child group (i.e. ID = 1 and ID = 3), the result row has to be populate with 'X' only for the current Child Group
if the original row NOT is related to a valued Child Group, but only to a Parent Group (ie ID = 2), the result row has to be populate with 'X' for both Child groups.

I tried with InScope, RowNumber... but i couldn't find a solution. Can you help me?

I would suggest you do this in your dataset query (assuming it's sql). It will be much easier. If you need help with that, then expand your example to show different parent groups and also explain how they are related to child groups, from you example it looks like they are related by the 1st character but that needs clearly explaining.
